# prevent numpy stack method change INT data to float

Tags: numpy, types, integer, stack

I try to stack three one dimension array. a and b are int that can be work as index and c is float. After I stack this three with axis=0, the a and b data change to float. I don't know why data type change after stack.

[image]

Comment: Make sure all component arrays are `int` dtype.  Your `c` is float!  `stack` (and all `concatenate`) make a nd array, with a common dtype.  You can't mix ints and floats.

Comment: Please do not use images for the code but a textual code section instead.

Comment: While it is possible to make arrays that mix int and float (object dtype or compound dtype), they don't offer any computational advantages.  Keeping the int and float arrays separate is usually better.